# Infopath COM object authentication failure using Web Service

Tags: c#, winforms, sharepoint, infopath

So I have a windows forms application that loads an infopath form(.xml) from a sharepoint library, and does some processing to it. I created an exe out of it and I just supply a sharepoint library url to it through cmd and it pulls up the form. 
I also have a web service which runs on an IIS server that calls the exe and displays infomartion for specific users. Now the problem is when I call the exe from then web service, it kept on asking for a login prompt. So i figured the web service must be running as a System account, and i supplied credentals through a number of ways

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(sharepoint_url);
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
              or
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("","");

I also tried System.Net.CredentialCache mycache = new System.Net.CredentialCache();

mycache.Add(formUrlName, "Basic", new System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "")); and
 request.Credentials = mycache;

But all the time i got an exception being thrown....Infopath cannot open this frm...the signature on this form is not from a trusted publisher.

Then I tried loading my project along with the web service and creating a new form ( Form form2 = new Form()), but doing the authentication procedure first. Now I get a http 401 unauthorized error.

(I use FormControl.Open(url) to open the form fromm the sharepoint library)

What am i doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I checked with the admin of the sharepoint library...apparently, the credentials are not being received at all. I dont know if they are not being sent properly or whether sharepoint is just dropping the credentials and not accepting it.

Comment: what version of SharePoint are you using ..2007 or 2010..? are you using System.Diagnostics.Process in your Web Service to Invoke the executable..??

Comment: I am using sharepoint 2007..Yes initially i used that, but then I dropped the exe and just called the form as an object from within the web service. But i got errors from both procedures.

Comment: are you using System.Diagnostic and creating a Process..?

Comment: Try this link and see if it might help - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wlwdev/thread/c338f79a-03fe-40c2-86d2-8ff785ed60b5/

Comment: I already refered to that. Before, the exe could never launch from the web service. After doing what they mentioned, the login prompt started appearing.

Comment: sounds like you may have locked yourself or that user account out..

Comment: if it shows user / password.. then you need to add Principal or Credential code but I am not completely sure since i am not aware of how your current network is setup..